# Rails - Remove special characters from phone input on form submission before saving to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-for

How can I change the input for a specific field when a form is submitted before it's written to the database? I'd like to be able to take any phone number format the user submits and remove all special characters and spaces from it before I save to the db. Then I'll use the number_to_phone method in my view to format the number how I want.

Comment: you should do it by overwriting the setter

Comment: Yes, that's what I was forgetting. Thanks @apneadiving

Comment: You can use [`before_save` callback of ActiveRecord](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

Comment: @WandMaker its not a good habit to use callbacks all over the place. A custom setter is the way to go there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override the setter and use regex so if your model is user and the field is phone_number

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def phone_number=(value)
    super(value.blank? ? nil : value.gsub(/[^\w\s]/, '')) 
  end
end
```

Comment: remains to  handle the `nil` case :)

Comment: @apneadiving true, not sure what he wants to do with nil but I updated it to at least handle nil

Answer (score 0):

You could use use `gsub` method in ruby to remove all spaces, hyphens and other characters from the string containing the phone no.
For further reading and usage, see entry in [APIdock]http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub).

Comment: That's not the part I was confused about, I guess there was no reason to include the part about removing all special characters. My real question is, how do I make a change to a form submission before it's written to the database. I think apneadiving gave me the answer I was looking for. Override the setter method

Comment: You could also modify the data on form submit on the client side using JavaScript.